# [Rviz]Is screen capture programmable on Rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to move camera viewpoint of Rviz and print screen by using C++ coding.
So I'v tried to find the way of this, I succeed move camera viewpoint but I don't get how to capture the screen by publishing massage.

Can ROS print the screen or capture Rviz camera view by publishing message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206404/%5Brviz%5Dis-screen-capture-programmable-on-rviz?/) by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-11**:
Same question as http://answers.ros.org/question/142351/publishing-virtual-camera-images-from-rviz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made our last recording using http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder suggested at the Rviz wiki page. It is really stable, even when running lots of ROS packages in the background, and also has a nice preview function of the recorded video.

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-08-24**:
very good software. I used it just now. I could meet my requirement without any training for usage. Thanks!